# Where are wordpress custom types stored?

Tags: custom-post-types, database, table

Where are custom types stored? Because when a custom type is created, in wp_posts, the post type is set to the `<new_custom_post_type>`. But where are the details of the new custom post type stored??

Answer (score 17):

I finally found the custom post type data. It is stored in the wp_post table where post_type = custom post type (e.g. "products"). The field (column) data is stored in wp_postmeta where the meta_key is the column name and meta_value is the column value.

This query will bring back all data associated with the custom post type "products":

```
SELECT P.ID, P.post_title, M.meta_key, M.meta_value
FROM wp_posts AS P
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS M ON M.post_id = P.ID
WHERE P.post_type = 'products' and P.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY post_title, meta_key
```

Answer (score 13):

The details of custom post types aren't stored anywhere, they're loaded at runtime with each request via [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) calls.

Comment: hmmmm, ok, thats y when I was trying to search for the info in the database, was not seeing them, thanks!

Comment: That is not true at all.

Comment: This may be true of the definition of the custom post type, but it does not address the question of where the data associated with each instance of a custom post type is stored.

Comment: @BobJones the question mentions the `wp_posts` table, so it seems pretty clear they know where the post data is stored. but if you have a different interpretation of the question, then perhaps you should add your own answer.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned by [@milo in this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49581/where-are-wordpress-custom-types-stored/49582#49582)

Post Types aren't actually stored separately in the database however that being said...

## via SQL

you can view all saved **PUBLIC** post types using the following sql query

```
SELECT DISTINCT( post_type ) FROM wp_posts;
```

Which will output something similar to:

```
+----------------------+
| post_type            |
+----------------------+
| attachment           |
| competition          |
| custom_css           |
| customize_changeset  |
| deprecated_log       |
| experts              |
| magazine             |
| nav_menu_item        |
| page                 |
| post                 |
| revision             |
+----------------------+
```

---

## via WP CLI

Additionally if you have access to **wp cli**, you can run:

```
wp post-type list
```

Which will output something like:

```
 +---------------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
 | name                | label                 | description  | hierarchical | public | capability_type     |
 +---------------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
 | post                | Posts                 |              |              | 1      | post                |
 | page                | Pages                 |              | 1            | 1      | page                |
 | attachment          | Media                 |              |              | 1      | post                |
 | revision            | Revisions             |              |              |        | post                |
 | nav_menu_item       | Navigation Menu Items |              |              |        | post                |
 | custom_css          | Custom CSS            |              |              |        | post                |
 | customize_changeset | Changesets            |              |              |        | customize_changeset |
 | deprecated_log      | Deprecated Calls      |              |              |        | post                |
 +---------------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: This is a better answer to the OP. thx.

Comment: Where is the information stored? I cannot find it in the DB

Comment: you could be looking at the wrong database. Look at your wp-config.php file for more info on which database your site is using

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function [`get_post_types`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) to get information on any and all post types that are active at that time.  To get info on a specific post type, use [`get_post_type_object`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object).

Comment: +1 - To make the returned post types from `get_post_types` only custom ones the parameter `_builtin` can be set to `false`

Answer (score 1):

WordPress default comes with some sample post types like pages, posts etc. Wordpress has given option to create our own custom post types also. Both default & custom posts are stored in single table "wp_posts" by differentiating all posts types based on "post_type" column in "wp_posts" table.

Eg: 
  pages--> post_type="page", 
  testiminials--> post_type="testimonials" 
 etc

To grab more information about this post_types, which would be available at "wp_postmeta " table.